# How to Populate the Multi Line Layout Fields Description and a Custom field value

Tags: community

I am creating an opportunity and adding a product to it. When I select a product and is directed to the page where we can edit quantity, salesprice etc. Here the description field and a custom field which I added through Opportunity Multi line layout is blank. I need them to be populated based on the product which was added with their respective description and discount.

Thanks,
Rushabh Shah

Comment: Hi Rushabh Shah, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom list button on Opportunity product object, which points to the same url as standard button,

But add additional query string parameters to prepopulate fields. So basically a URL override.

Remove standard "Add Product" button and add this new button on layout.

Comment: this has limitations if `Prompt for Products` feature is enabled on Opportunity